# Need to $watch property from within an accordion (Angular-UI) but won't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

We're building a page with Angular, Angular-UI and UI-Bootstrap. The last one includes a directive for accordion, which simplifies a quite repetitive task of building up an accordion and an accordion group.

We, however, must watch for changes from an input inside that accordion. Problem is that the accordion has a child scope and it work work.

[Here's a sample from Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/Vot79B8qHhrQI26GYuZT/) (open the accordion by clicking on "Just a heading").

Is it possible to track changes into that input?

Answer (score 0):

Try to `$emit` a custom event. It should bubble up to your scope. Worst case you should be able to listen to that event on the `$rootScope`

so something like :

```
   $scope.$emit('input:change',{DATA});
```

on the accordion controller

and

```
$scope.$on('input:change'),function(data){
//do stuff with the change in input
})
```